# Faster alternative to np.where for a sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

Given a large array `a` which is sorted along each row, is there faster alternative to numpy's `np.where` to find the indices where `min_v <= a <= max_v`? I would imagine that leveraging the sorted nature of the array should be able to speed things up.

Here's an example of a setup using `np.where` to find the given indices in a large array.

```
import numpy as np

# Initialise an example of an array in which to search
r, c = int(1e2), int(1e6)
a = np.arange(r*c).reshape(r, c)

# Set up search limits
min_v = (r*c/2)-10
max_v = (r*c/2)+10

# Find indices of occurrences
idx = np.where(((a >= min_v) & (a <= max_v)))
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the expression is iterating over `a` a number of times, each relatively fast, but together the time accumulates.  There's the `a>=min_v` test, the `&` combination, and finally the actual `where`, which just seeks `True` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `np.searchsorted` with the 100 million numbers in the original example with the not up-to-date NumPy version 1.12.1 (can't tell about newer versions), it is not much faster than `np.where`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('np.where(((a >= min_v) & (a <= max_v)))', number=10, globals=globals())
6.685825735330582
>>> timeit.timeit('np.searchsorted(a.ravel(), [min_v, max_v])', number=10, globals=globals())
5.304438766092062
```

But, despite the NumPy docs for `searchsorted` say *This function uses the same algorithm as the builtin python `bisect.bisect_left` and `bisect.bisect_right` functions,* the latter are a lot faster:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> timeit.timeit('bisect.bisect_left(a.base, min_v), bisect.bisect_right(a.base, max_v)', number=10, globals=globals())
0.002058468759059906
```

Therefore, I'd use this:

```
idx = np.unravel_index(range(bisect.bisect_left(a.base, min_v),
                             bisect.bisect_right(a.base, max_v)), a.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

r, c = 10, 100
a = np.arange(r*c).reshape(r, c)

min_v = ((r * c) // 2) - 10
max_v = ((r * c) // 2) + 10

# Old method
idx = np.where(((a >= min_v) & (a <= max_v)))

# With searchsorted
i1 = np.searchsorted(a.ravel(), min_v, 'left')
i2 = np.searchsorted(a.ravel(), max_v, 'right')
idx2 = np.unravel_index(np.arange(i1, i2), a.shape)
print((idx[0] == idx2[0]).all() and (idx[1] == idx2[1]).all())
# True
```